# Cant find AsNoTracking in entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using EF v. 6 with EF Designer from Database.

When I've added my model I added two new associations (that doesn't exist in the database).

The problem I have is that I get OutOfMemoryException and I wanna try using AsNoTracking, but I can't use the method for some reason (it can't be found?). Or have I made something wrong with my setup?

Except the two new associations I haven't changed anything in my model..

```
    private IEnumerable<Position> GetPositionsByDate(DateTime navDate, PositionType positionType)
    {
        IEnumerable<Position> positions = Branch.Positions.Where(p => p.PositionDate == navDate && GetPositionType(p) == positionType);

        //todo: add grouping of same positions
        return positions;
    }
```

I've tried Branch.Positions.AsNoTracking, and also at the end..

Comment: System.Data.Entity namespace?[msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679352%28v=vs.103%29.aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679352%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks!! But Why do I have to Use .AsQueryable().AsNoTracking() ?

Comment: `AsNoTracking()` takes an `IQueryable<T>`.  That's why.